# setCellType(CellType.STRING) is deprecated

Tags: java, apache-poi

He actualizado el POI de mi pom.xml de la versión 3.11 a la 4.1.2 y al revisar los cambios me ha salido un warning que dice que "setCellType is deprecated". He estado buscando por diversos sitios pero no he encontrado nada, no consigo un equivalente claro para:

```
celda.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
```

Por si os es de ayuda las importaciones son las siguientes:

- **setCellType** lo estoy importando de **org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell**
- **CellType** de **org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType**

El método que quiero solucionar sería el siguiente:

```
public static String leerDevolverCeldaString(Cell celda) {
    String valor = null;
    if(celda != null) {
        try {
            valor = celda.getStringCellValue();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.info("No se puede leer la celda como cadena." + e);
            try {
                celda.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
                valor = celda.getStringCellValue();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LOG.info(CELL_EMPTY + ex);
                valor = null;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Evitamos espacios en blanco
    if(valor != null) {
        valor = valor.trim();
    }
    return valor;
}
```

Como veis, la solución necesito es como setear el tipo de celda de un Cell que estoy procesando para así, seteandole el tipo a String, poder obtener el valor en ese formato aunque sea un tipo numérico.

¿Alguien ha tenido este problema y sabe un equivalente para solucionar este warning?
Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Hm, podrías por favor [edit] la pregunta e indicar los paquetes o clases que estás importando para esa línea? Es para saber de dónde estás sacando `setCellType` y `CellType.STRING`. Gracias :)

Comment: @Alfabravo modificado. Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

La [documentación oficial](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType-) siempre es el primer camino a seguir. Si esa no ayuda, ya uno se busca la vida de otra forma.

Ahí dice que

> This method is deprecated and will be removed in POI 5.0. Use explicit setCellFormula(String), setCellValue(...) or setBlank() to get the desired result.

Que en español latinoamericano diría que *no te ocupes del tipo y simplemente asigna el valor usando uno de esos métodos que ya están disponibles*. En POI 5 ni siquiera vas a encontrar ese método y va a fallar la invocación.

Si revisas en detalle [esa página](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html) de documentación para la clase `Cell`, verás que sobrecargan la función `setCellValue` dependiendo del tipo de dato en el parámetro de entrada :) Por eso ya no importa fijar el tipo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: @Alvarofb7 con gusto! Si te resuelve el problema, recuerda marcarla como aceptada, así otros con la misma pregunta sabrán que esa respuesta funciona

Comment: No es la solución de lo que quería después de revisar bien la documentación. Mi intención es setear el tipo de celda a String, no setearle cierto valor a una celda. Coloco el código del método en la pregunta. Gracias aún así por tu respuesta!

Comment: @Alvarofb7 Te estoy diciendo en perfecto español que la solución es NO FIJARLE EL TIPO porque lo infiere del tipo de dato. Entiendes el concepto de sobrecarga? Si necesitas usar un int o algo, te corresponde hacer el cast ANTES de asignarlo. De hecho, es una mejor opción que "asumir el cast" al hacerlo en el orden que usas (que la celda haga el cast y dependas de Excel)